# Booststrap 4 Grid System , I'm not able to achieve this layout

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I can do this layout in normal CSS using flex and grid, But I need to know how to do this using bootstrap 4, There is nothing left to try .

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3 bg-success" style="height:500px">d</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 bg-primary" style="height:250px">d</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 bg-info" style="height:500px">d</div>
    </div>        
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 bg-info" style="height:250px">z</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I need to get[image]

Comment: Bootstrap is very limited. It lets you create basic layouts with awful markup relatively quickly. Just write the CSS yourself. It's a much better approach in the long run.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I guess spending more time on trying to achieve this in bootstrap could be waste of time. But i thought if i do this with bootstrap then i don't have to code again for responsiveness

Comment: When you create a layout using Bootstrap you do have to write code for responsiveness, you just have to do it using the limited set of classes that Bootstrap provides.

Comment: Okay. Just to clarify, Is this layout impossible to create in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the working snippet will help you

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 bg-success" style="height:500px">d</div>
<div class="col-sm-4" style="height:500px">
    <div class="row" style="position:relative;height:500px;">
        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary" style="height:200px">d</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 bg-warning" style="height:200px;position:absolute; bottom:0;">d</div>
    </div>
</div>        
<div class="col-sm-4 bg-info" style="height:500px">z</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The layout is three columns with the center column having 2 rows.
Try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm bg-success" style="height:500px">d</div>
  <div class="col-sm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 bg-primary" style="height:250px">d</div>        
    </div>        
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 bg-info" style="height:250px">z</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm bg-info" style="height:500px">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, Hope it will help you.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="height:100px; background-color:black">d</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 ">

            <div class="col-auto p-2 bg-primary" style="height:100px;">a</div>
            <div class="box mx-auto bg-info" style="height:100px;">b</div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bg-info" style="height:100px">z</div>

    </div>
```

I divided the one row into 3 columns, both side boxes has a size of 3 and mid box have a size of 6 then check the class **col-auto-p2** & **box mx-auto**.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one with Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="bg-success" style="height:500px">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row h-100">
                <div class="col-12 h-50" style="padding-bottom: 10%;">
                    <div class="bg-info h-100">

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 h-50" style="padding-top: 10%;">
                    <div class="bg-info h-100">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="bg-success" style="height:500px">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can change the `padding` on inner columns. Don't forget to put `row` inside a `container` or `container-fluid` as described here 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/

> Containers provide a means to center and horizontally pad your site’s contents. Use .container for a responsive pixel width or .container-fluid for width: 100% across all viewport and device sizes.